# sbt - Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 Error when executed in Jdk 1.7

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have a jar which has been created using sbt on my local system with the following configuration:
JDK 1.8, 
SBT 1.2.8

I wanted to execute the jar on a VM which has JDK 1.7. To create the jar such that it can be executed in JDK 1.7, I added the following to my build.sbt:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")
scalacOptions := Seq("-target:jvm-1.7")

javaHome := Some(file("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_80"))
```

However despite specifying sbt to target JDK 1.7 I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/uic/mapreduce/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:141)
```

All other threads for this problem seem to be resolved with the above changes. I seem to be missing something here.

Comment: you're using Scala 2.11, I hope, and not some later version? I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on my own machine; see https://gist.github.com/SethTisue/05d8e78d7126d5213f276bd70c13d079